# how to out put a reverse string array java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to reverse array String from the user and I had one problem how can I out put the elements without new array.
I don't know what should I write to output the content.
However, I tried most of the examples*(a[i], a[i+1]) and if run it I got null.

### here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;
    String temp =null;
    String o=null;
    int pos =0;
    String a [];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: "); 
    o = kb.nextLine(); 
    a = new String [o.length()];

    for( i =0; i< (o.length()/2)-1; i++){
        temp = a[i];
         a[i] = a[o.length()-(i+1)];
         a[o.length()-(i+1)] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Arrays.toString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array) to output the contents of an array, combined with `System.out.println`, of course.

Comment: System.out.println(new StringBuilder("reverse this string").reverse().toString());

Comment: A lesson in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - We don't care how you get a string, so cut out all of the input blurb and just give us `String o = "string to reverse";`

Comment: I ll try so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Collections.reverse(asList(arraytoReverse));

wrap your array within asList() then call the collections' reverse on the list created.

Comment: I am still beginner in array so if you have another way. That's will be great thank you in advance fro response

Answer (score 0):

It's printing null because you are not providing the string to the array of the string. So, it printing `null`. If you want to reverse the array of string you can simply use a `delimiter` to read the string into the array of string. And to reverse it you can use `StringBuilder` and `string.append()` method to concatenate the string. If you just want to reverse a string just use `StringBuilder` and `reverse()` method. Try the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String str = in.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Output :

```
 Enter a sentence: This is a string
 gnirts a si sihT
```

Comment: I am not looking for switching the word. I wantto switch every thing in the array

Comment: @tariq Almasshni  then why were you using an array? Check the code above that should do it.